# Regex to remove all spaces, periods and other non-word characters from a string

Tags: c#, regex

I have this `[^\w\.@-]` regex expression that removes any character that is not a word character from the given string it works fine. Except for the two cases that I want it to cater also that is to also remove any spaces   or full-stops `.` if one exists in the string.

How should I change this regex? I tried getting a hold of regex over internet but it doesn't seem that easy.

```
Regex.Replace(title, @"[^\w\.@-]", "",RegexOptions.None, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
```

Comment: Do you want to keep these characters? `. @ -` As asked, it sounds like you just want to remove \W (all non-word characters). You also don't need to escape the `.` inside a character class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove dot from your **negative character class**. You only need to place those character in your negative character class that you want to keep in the replaced string.

You can use:

```
string repl = Regex.Replace(title, @"[^\w@-]", "", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
```

Space is already being removed since space is not considered a word character.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is fine. It appears that the problem is in the way that you are trying to use it.

The replacement does not happen in place, you need to capture the result in order to get the new string:

```
var newTitle = Regex.Replace(title, @"[^\w\.@-]", "", RegexOptions.None, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
```

This expression works as expected ([demo](http://ideone.com/PluZqC)) - it keeps only word characters, dots, dashes, and at `@` signs.